# $\lambda$-Decomposition for Connes' Cyclic Complex

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, cyclic-homology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $A$ be a commutative unital $k$-algebra. Then the cyclic homology of $A$ has a $\lambda$-decomposition:
$$HC_{n}(A)=HC_{n}^{(1)}(A)\oplus \cdots \oplus HC_{n}^{(n)}(A).$$

The construction of this decomposition is described in section 4.6 in Loday's *Cyclic homology* in terms of normalized Connes' bicomplex $\overline{\mathcal{B}}(A)$.

I want to know that can we construct the same $\lambda$-decomposition via decomposing Connes' cyclic complex $C^{\lambda}(A)$? If we can, can some one provide some references about this? Thanks a lot.